# Bash to zsh actual syntax differences, such as brackets in 'if'

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to move some scripts from bash to zsh (ideally, I'd like them to work in either).
I have two questions, both of which I've tried but failed to find answers to here and via search engines:

1: Where can I get a list of key difference in zsh *syntax* or *semantics*, not UI? Easy to find explanations of how zsh is great, how to chsh to it, what .zshenv is -- but nothing about how actual code has to differ.

2: What's the deal with brackets in "if"? In bash, I tend to use single brackets except where  double are actually needed. Most of my bash code works just fine in zsh, but some single-[] "if"s complain

```
= not found
```

Same result on MacOSX and Ubuntu. Searching gets lots of hits for "command not found", but if there are any for this case, they're buried.

Afaict, the problem occurs with binary operators like "==", but not with unary ones like "-d" etc (trivial test code below). Assuming that's correct, I can just fix by rote -- but what's actually going on here?

```
A=1
B=0

echo "Equality test with double brackets"
if [[ "$A" == "$B" ]]; then
    echo "A is B"
else
    echo "A is not B"
fi

echo "A file test with single brackets"
if [ -d "$HOME" ]; then
    echo "Home exists"
 else
    echo "Home does not exist"
fi

echo "Equality test with single brackets"
if [ "$A" == "$B" ]; then
    echo "A is B"
else
    echo "A is not B"
fi
```

Comment: Google "difference between bash and zsh". But your best bet is to use POSIX shell syntax, then it should be compatible with all shells.

Comment: c.f. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-unix-shells-humble-if for a pretty good tutorial. There's also a cheat-sheet at https://steinbaugh.com/posts/posix.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: I can't reproduce that error on zsh 5.8.

Comment: `==`, as an argument to `[` rather than a shell operator, (at least prior to 5.8, which I don't have to test with at the moment) is subject to '=' expansion before `[` is executed. (See FILENAME EXPANSION in `man zshexpn`.)

Comment: Even if you don't want to restrict yourself to POSIX-defined features (arrays are very useful), knowing what they are makes it easier to know what things should work identically in `zsh` and `bash`, and which things may work differently even if they look the same. `==`, for example, is *not* the equality operator for `[...]`; a shell like `dash` will treat it as a syntax error. `bash` allows it, as will `zsh` *if* the `==` is quoted or escaped to avoid '=' expansion.

Comment: It looks like `unseptopt equals` will allow the use of an unquoted `==` in single brackets; that may be the reason others were unable to reproduce the error. I do not know what else might be affected by changing the option.

Comment: One thing that bites me is that bash arrays are 0-indexed and zsh arrays are 1-indexed. Trying to write scripts that work on both is a total pain as soon as you go beyond basic sh constructs, and sometimes even then.

Comment: @ user1934428 -- that's definitely the problem, thanks! If I can figure out how, I flag this as a duplicate.